# right-aligned table from csv

Tags: tables, horizontal-alignment

I have a `csv` file formatted like this one:

```
"","head 1","head 2","head 3"
"count 1","23","24","25"
"percentage 1","23%","24%","25%"
"count 2","53","54","55"
"percentage 2","53%","54%","55%"
```

I'm using `datatool` package to convert `csv` to `table`. I want to format the table to right-align. But right-align only works when the `csv` is formatted like this one: 
`"row 2","23","24","25"`

I know I can manually adjust the table to get what I need. But the `csv` file is dynamic (the `csv` file is generated by the system).

How can I get a right-aligned table, fix the `csv` source or fix the LaTeX?

---

This is my the sample LaTeX code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[small,compact]{titlesec}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{palatino}

\usepackage{datatool}

\begin{document}

\section{CSV Test}

\DTLloaddb{csvtest}{csvtest.csv}            
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\DTLdisplaydb{csvtest}              
\caption{CSV Table Test}        
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

And the csv:

```
"","Head 1","Head 2"
"Count 1","15","99"
"","1.92\%","12.69\%"
"Count 2","33","353"
"","1.99\%","21.28\%"
```

Comment: How about making a script to pre-process your `csv` file?

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx! It's not necessary to sign your questions (as there is already a box with your username below it) or to begin them with a greeting.

Comment: Can you add a minimal document that shows what you've done that doesn't work? (The document should load only `datatool`, read in a minimal CSV file and attempt to format it the way you want.)

Comment: The answer section is for solutions to the question only. I moved the example code to the question. You can edit it to provide more information one posted. You can and should also use `<pre>...</pre>` HTML tags around non-TeX code like CSV instead of `\`...\`<br>`.

Answer (score 1):

```
\DTLloaddb{csvtest}{csvtest.csv}            
\begin{table}[htbp]
\centering
\renewcommand{\dtlstringalign}{r}
\DTLdisplaydb{csvtest}              
\caption{CSV Table Test}        
\end{table}
```

The quoted entries are interpreted by `datatool` as strings, so you need to help the package by telling it how to align strings.